# Color palette (colors used) for RibbonWindow's Office 2007 Black theme?

Tags: wpf, themes, colors, ribbon, color-scheme

I am using the Office 2007 Black theme for my RibbonWindow and really like all of the colors it uses. Here is the resource dictionary included in my ribbon window's resources.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/RibbonControlsLibrary;component/Themes/Office2007Black.xaml"/>
```

I would like to mirror the colors of this theme in my user controls. Is there any resource that lists the main colors in this theme?

I've taken screenshots to get the hex value of some of the colors, but was hoping there may be a color palette for this theme available somewhere.

Thanks,
Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steven, you know what? Yesterday, I was doing the same thing. I did manage to get the themes by using a tool called Reflector and an addin - "Baml Viewer".

Baml Viewer disassembles the BAML stored in the dll to the corresponding XAML.

Reflector: http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

If you really are not in mood to figure out the rest or may be you need the themes right now do let me know.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I have been making good progress on my application, but will definitely be doing a color rehaul after extracting the theme colors.

If you have the themes handy then I would certainly appreciate them, if not I can get them myself using the tools you recommended.

Thanks again, and sorry for the delayed reply.

Answer (score 1):

These namespaces in .NET framewordk may help

Microsoft.Office.Core.ThemeColor

Microsoft.Office.Core.ThemeColorScheme

System.Windows.Forms.ProfessionalColors - Provides Color structures that are colors of a Windows display element.